# Getting a column without grouping by it - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following query to get data from my table:

```
SELECT base_asset_trade, base_asset_icon,
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN 1 END) AS sold,
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false' THEN 1 END) AS bought,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN trade_value  END) AS sold_trade_value,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false'  THEN trade_value  END) AS bought_trade_value,
       COUNT(base_asset_trade) AS total_trades
FROM trades
WHERE trade_time / 1000 > (extract(epoch from now()) - (86400)*1) 
GROUP BY base_asset_trade, base_asset_icon
ORDER BY total_trades DESC
```

This is the schema of the table.

```
id (int)
exchange_name (VARCHAR)
exchange_icon (VARCHAR)
trade_time (bigint)
price_quote (int)
price_usd (int)
trade_value (int)
base_asset_icon (VARCHAR)
qty (int)
quoteQty (int)
is_buyer_maker (boolean)
pair (VARCHAR)
base_asset_trade (VARCHAR)
quote_asset_trade (VARCHAR)
```

Now I need the data grouped only by **base_asset_trade** but I need the *base_asset_icon* as well. How do I get the icon without grouping by it?

Comment: If you do not want to `group by base_asset_icon`, and there is more than one `base_asset_icon` per `base_asset_trade`, then which `base_asset_icon` should be returned on the row?

Comment: doesn't the DB automatically pick?

Comment: No it doesn't, not on Postgres.  You need to articulate _which_ value you want.

Comment: It does not, hence the error message when you try.  You can wrap `base_asset_icon` in a `min()` or `max()` if you do not really care which is returned.

Comment: Also, the sum function is not adding up the trade_values correctly. How exactly is the query adding them? I needed the trade_value against every base_asset_trade added.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** for each `base_asset_icon` there is always one and only one `base_asset_trade`, then you can use any aggregate function (`MAX`, `MIN`) to fetch it out in SELECT statement, i.e.:

```sql
SELECT base_asset_trade, MAX(base_asset_icon),
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN 1 END) AS sold,
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false' THEN 1 END) AS bought,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN trade_value  END) AS sold_trade_value,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false'  THEN trade_value  END) AS bought_trade_value,
       COUNT(base_asset_trade) AS total_trades
FROM trades
WHERE trade_time / 1000 > (extract(epoch from now()) - (86400)*1) 
GROUP BY base_asset_trade
ORDER BY total_trades DESC
```

**Otherwise**, you can use an aggregate function that does not lose values, such as `array_agg`:

```sql
SELECT base_asset_trade, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(base_asset_icon), ','),
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN 1 END) AS sold,
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false' THEN 1 END) AS bought,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN trade_value  END) AS sold_trade_value,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false'  THEN trade_value  END) AS bought_trade_value,
       COUNT(base_asset_trade) AS total_trades
FROM trades
WHERE trade_time / 1000 > (extract(epoch from now()) - (86400)*1) 
GROUP BY base_asset_trade
ORDER BY total_trades DESC
```

and if you want to keep the values as a string, you can use `ARRAY_TO_STRING` function too:

```sql
SELECT base_asset_trade, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(base_asset_icon), ','),
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN 1 END) AS sold,
       count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false' THEN 1 END) AS bought,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'true' THEN trade_value  END) AS sold_trade_value,
       sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'false'  THEN trade_value  END) AS bought_trade_value,
       COUNT(base_asset_trade) AS total_trades
FROM trades
WHERE trade_time / 1000 > (extract(epoch from now()) - (86400)*1) 
GROUP BY base_asset_trade
ORDER BY total_trades DESC
```